# Flash fallback in HTML5 video tag does not work in Opera

Tags: html, cross-browser, html5-video, opera

```html
<video controls>
    <source src="video.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    <object>
    ...
    </object>
</video>
```

This HTML5 video tag with a mp4 video and a Flash fallback works in every single browser all over, except from Opera on PC.

But if I move the "object" out of "video", it will work - so that means Flash is properly installed and working.

Is there a solution to this, or do I have to make some sort of a workaround by checking for browser and then displaying a pure Flash player for Opera?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Flash fallback only works on old browsers that can't process the `<video>` element natively - but that doesn't include Opera. Opera tries to play your HTML5 media... and fails.

Your issue is that Opera can't play the mp4 file. Try adding a fallback webm version to support it:

```
<video controls>
    <source src="video.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    <source src="video.webm" type="video/webm">
    <object>
    ...
    </object>
</video>
```

Comment: Thanks, that explains quite a lot. But I don't want to force my client to upload two different formats for each video. Is there no other way to solve this rather than doing my workaround explained above?

Comment: Well that is certainly a pitfall of using HTML5 media. Read this note about supported file types: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Supported_media_formats. To stick with a single format, you could try the "Flash fallbackforward" approach used by MediaElement.js http://mediaelementjs.com/.

Comment: MediaElement.js is great, but it would have been even better if I could use plain html5 with a simple Flash fallback, instead of dealing with the js and css files of MediaElement.js. I'm a fan of simplicity.